# how can I do a task that I don't like it?

Tags: software-development, entry-level

I'm a junior software engineer (new graduate) and I have only 5 months in my current job (first).
While I did the interviews with my manager he told me many things that are not true (in other words he cheated me to accept the post and came to his society).
Listen to such words I refused an other opportunity of job in other company more famous than the one where I work now and with more advantages than I get now.
I chosen the current society for only one reason: learn more and more because in a startup with 20 persons I have more chance to enhance my profile and my acknowledgment.
At the beginning, he asked me to do a task (it's not a task of an engineer).
I did it but the deadline is not fixed because the manger extend it every month.
After 4 months, I ask him for a meeting and I told him that I'm bored of this task and I want to do a real job of an engineer containing design and a real study of project to struggle the problems and resolving it before coding.
He told me that I don't have the right to intervene in the architecture of the society and of the project and I'm a beginner and I don't have the right to discuss about that.
The result of the meeting I was changed from the current to another project more boring than the first one because the program was bad written.
I want to quit because I can't continue to work like that but I'm afraid if they told other companies bad news about me and they don't accept me in the future interviews.
Can anyone advise me ?

Comment: So what is your actual question? Have a look at the [help] for the types of question we can and can't answer here. We can't really give you the kind of personalised career advice you seem to be looking for.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to pay your dues and work your way up the ranks like everyone else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not happy with your job, and you can't get it to change, then you look for a position elsewhere until you find something better. Make sure that you read your employment contract carefully. It is very unlikely that anyone would bother to tell stories about you.

Now I'm not sure what you mean by "I was changed from the current to another project more boring than the first one because the program was bad written". So is this a software development job, where you are asked to maintain a badly written program? Do you find this boring? You could look at it as a challenge - turn a badly written program into a well written one. Ask yourself: The job that you are asked to do, is that something that needs to be done by a software engineer? If the answer is yes, then who do you think should do it, if you don't want to do it?